# Javascript encryption in Crypto decryption in CryptoJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, encryption, cryptography, cryptojs

I'm trying to encrypt server side (crypto Node) and decrypt client side (CryptoJS). I can create the key using cryptoJS, and can encrypt and decrypt when the same individual library is used however the issue is I cannot encrypt with Crypto but decrypt with CryptoJS, which is the real world scenario. There are no errors, just an empty response.

Any help greatly appreciated please!

```
iv = crypto.randomBytes(16),
orig = 'A confidential message.';
//Crypto JS creates key
var password = "sixteen byte key";
var salt = CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.random(128/8);
var key = CryptoJS.PBKDF2(password, salt, { keySize: 128 / 32, iterations: 1000 });
console.log("step1 generated key: "+ key);

//Convert key for crypto use - as a Buffer
var hashHex = key.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Hex);
var hash = new Buffer(hashHex,'hex');

//Test encryption and decryption with crypto (Node)
//use CryptoJS key to encrypt data using crypto cipheriv
var cipher2 = crypto.createCipheriv('aes-128-cbc', hash, iv); //iv must be a buffer
var encrypted1 = cipher2.update(orig, 'utf8', 'hex');
var encrypted2 = encrypted1 += cipher2.final('hex');
console.log("Crypto string:", encrypted2.toString());

// Start decrypt
var decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv('aes-128-cbc', hash, iv);
var dec = decipher.update(encrypted2, 'hex', 'utf8')
dec += decipher.final('utf8');
console.log("Crypto decrypted msg:", dec);

//test with crypto JS (ie the client)
//CryptoJS key is a string
var encryptedCJS = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(orig, key.toString(), { iv: iv, mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC});
console.log("CryptoJS encrypted: "+encryptedCJS);

var decryptedCryptoJS = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(encryptedCJS, key.toString(), { mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC, iv: iv });
console.log("CryptoJS decrypted msg: "+decryptedCryptoJS.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8));

//This part does not work - use message encrypted by crypto but cannot decrypt with CryptoJS. decryptedCryptoJSFinal is empty
var decryptedCryptoJSFinal = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(encrypted2, key.toString(), {iv: iv, mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC});
console.log("FINAL CryptoJS decrypted: "+decryptedCryptoJSFinal.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8));
```

I think the output of crypto encryption must be a different format to output of CryptoJS encryption but I cannot find the issue. 
Overall I then intend to send the encrypted data as JSON for decryption on the client by CryptoJS.

Comment: FWIW you can use the same node `crypto` API if you use webpack/browserify/etc.

Comment: @mscdex Good point thanks. FWIW I wanted to use a different lib as the server really could be Java, .Net etc. BTW I think I've cracked it, CryptoJS expects a 'word array' to decrypt so I think the issue is there. Still proving the fix at the mo.

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is in the client, if you pass  the 'key' and the 'iv' as strings into 'CryptoJS.AES.encrypt', then CryptoJS takes your 'key' and a random 'salt' and generates a different secret key for the cipher. You can verify it generating different cipherTexts from the same clearText with the same key and iv, they will always be different, because a different secret key is generated inside CryptoJS each time you run the function.

To avoid this you need to pass the 'key' and 'iv' encoded (in 'hex' or 'base64' depending in the code you use) and then CryptoJS interprets that it doesn't have to generate a secret key and takes your 'key' to cipher.

Check this example:

```
//BACKEND with node crypto aes-256-cbc->  generate key and ciphertext
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
var crypto = require('crypto');
var algorithm = 'aes-256-cbc';
var inputEncoding = 'utf8';
var outputEncoding = 'base64';
var pt = 'HELLO';

//generate key and iv
var masterKey = "253D3FB468A0E24677C28A624BE0F939";
var salt  = "0000000000000000";
var keySize = 256/8;
var ivSize = 128/8;
var iterations = 100;
var outputKey = crypto.pbkdf2Sync(masterKey, salt, iterations, keySize+ivSize, "sha1");

// obtain key and IV  splitting outputKey
var buffer = new Buffer(outputKey, inputEncoding);
var secretKey = buffer.slice(0, keySize);
var iv = buffer.slice(keySize, (keySize+ivSize)); 

console.log('secretKey->',secretKey.toString('base64'));
console.log('iv->',iv.toString('base64'));       

//encrypt
var encrypt = crypto.createCipheriv(algorithm, secretKey, iv);
var encrypted = encrypt.update(pt, inputEncoding, outputEncoding);
encrypted += encrypt.final(outputEncoding);
console.log('Ciphering "%s"', pt);
//We obtain a 
console.log('CipherText base64' string "%s ', encrypted.toString());



//FRONTEND with node CryptoJS aes-256-cbc->  generate same key and obtain cleartext
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
var masterKey = "253D3FB468A0E24677C28A624BE0F939";
var salt ="0000000000000000";
var iterations = 100; 
var keySize = 256;
var ivSize = 128;
var outputKey = CryptoJS.PBKDF2(masterKey, salt, {
  keySize: (keySize+ivSize)/32,
  iterations: iterations
});
// the underlying words arrays might have more content than was asked: remove insignificant words
outputKey.clamp();

// split key and IV
var secretKey = CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.create(outputKey.words.slice(0, 
keySize/32));
var iv = CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.create(outputKey.words.slice(keySize/32));

console.log('secretKey->', secretKey.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64));
console.log('iv->', iv.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64));

var decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(ct, secretKey,{iv: iv});//Default mode CBC { mode: CryptoJS.mode.CFB });
console.log('CipherText->', ct);
console.log('ClearText decrypted', decrypted.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8));
```